# SASS: Reverse map-keys

Tags: css, sass, material-design

I have a problem with the generated CSS order. 
An element should not be visible on phones (but on tablets & desktops), so it gets the following class:

```
.d-none .d-tablet-block
```

In the CSS file 'd-none' comes after 'd-tablet-block'. Thus 'd-tablet-block' is always overwritten.

**This is my current CSS. It is generated by a SASS Mixin.**

```
@media (min-width: 840px) {
  .d-desktop-inline {
    display: inline!important
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .d-tablet-inline {
    display: inline!important
  }
}

.d-inline {
  display: inline!important
}
```

**I need the same CSS but in that order**

```
.d-inline {
  display: inline!important
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .d-tablet-inline {
    display: inline!important
  }
}

@media (min-width: 840px) {
  .d-desktop-inline {
    display: inline!important
  }
}
```

My breakpoints come from Google Web Components. If I put Phone up here and Desktop down, the CSS will be generated in the correct order.
But unfortunately other components of Google Web Components will not work anymore.

```
$mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints: (
  desktop: 840px,
  tablet: 480px,
  phone: 0
);
```

Here is the SASS Mixin:

```
@function breakpoint-infix($name, $breakpoints: $mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints) {
  @return if(breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints) == null, "", "-#{$name}");
}

@function breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints: $mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: map-get($breakpoints, $name);
  @return if($min != 0, $min, null);
}

@mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints);

  @if $min {
    @media (min-width: $min) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @content;
  }
}

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints);

    .d#{$infix}-none         { display: none !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-inline       { display: inline !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-inline-block { display: inline-block !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-block        { display: block !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-table        { display: table !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-table-row    { display: table-row !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-table-cell   { display: table-cell !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-flex         { display: flex !important; }
    .d#{$infix}-inline-flex  { display: inline-flex !important; }
  }
}
```

**Can I somehow reverse the map-keys ($ mdc-layout-grid-breakpoints)?**

Comment: The Mixin is from Bootstrap 4. Unfortunately it does not work the way it is now. See description.

Comment: [Does this link help, maybe?](https://gist.github.com/seanislegend/107ccf9c81ec9fd1aae0)

Comment: Yes! It is working!